# My submit button in my php form doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, submit

My submit button does nothing? Anyone know why

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

```
<form action="registerProduct.php" method="post">
    Namn: <input type="text" name="prodName"><br>
    Pris: <input type="text" name="prodPrice"><br>
    Bildlänk: <input type="text" name="prodImg"><br>
    Lagerstatus: <input type="text" name="prodStatus"><br>
    Beskrivning: <input type="text" name="prodDescrip"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: what mean by not working?

Comment: Your code validates and successfully submits a form when I run it with Firefox 33.  Either something you haven't posted is breaking the form or I do not understand what "does nothing" means.